# how to lock orientation for some screen sizes?

Tags: android

i am developing an application which will run on all devices ranging from 4.7 inch devices and above both in portrait and landscape orientation.

Now the issue is, i have around 50 or so activities and i want to lock orientation to vertical if the device screen size is **less than equal to 5 inch**. I can set orientation lock using the code below :-

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

Above code i can use to lock orientation and below code for display metrics :-

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

or

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Now my question is, that what is the appropriate method to lock orientation for devices <= 5 inch and do i have to write this code in all my activities ?
Also i cannot extend using baseActivity because most of the activities are already extending custom listener classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best OOP's practices that always create a "BaseActivity" or "BaseFragmentActivity" to take the benefit of code reusability and less redundant. The standard way to restrict the orientation of an activity in the manifest.

But you've have to restrict based on conditions and also don't want to re-write in every activity. So my suggestion to create "Base Activity" that extends to all of your sub activities.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
        //...

        if(isScreenLarge()) {
            // width > height, better to use Landscape
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }

    public boolean isScreenLarge() {
        final int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
        return screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE
                || screenSize == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }
}
```

Now extend all your activities with `BaseActivity`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot extend using because most of the activities are already extending custom listener classes

Comment: Ok. Then you have to create a Util that has a static method which takes relevant params {activity, ...} to provide the reusability feature. But you have to call Util.setRequestedOrienation(activity, ...) from each activity. I would say that it's more like design architecture problem which will always put you in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base Activity class that has the code.  The other 50 extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Create base activity all your 50 activities extend. put your locking logic in `onResume()` or `onCreate()` of that base activity and lock the orientation there.

BTW: 50 activities is really a lot. Tried fragments?

Comment: It is just an example - 50 activities or fragments. The main issue is orientation lock